# target="_blank" keep downloading image instead opening other page

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

The problem when i click the image, the image is downloading instead of opening to other tab.

```
@foreach($image as $get_image_value)
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <figure>
                    <a href="{{url('/storage/'.$get_image_value->image.'')}}" target="_tab">
                        <img src="{{url('/storage/'.$get_image_value->image.'')}}">
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </div>
    @endforeach
```

Sample image

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Try to check mime type of image.

Comment: in the code, target='_tab' is given , in the question you are asking about target='_blank'.. any justification?

Answer (score 6):

If the image is downloading then either:

- The browser is configured to download that file format
- The server is sending a [`Content-Disposition: attachment` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) to tell the browser to download it.
- The server is sending the wrong `Content-Type` header for the image.

You can't do anything about the first case.

The second case you will need to find the code or server configuration that is setting that header and change it.

The third case you will need to fix the server configuration so it sends the correct `Content-Type`. This *might* be a case of renaming the file so it has the correct file extension.

Comment: Hi @Quentin as of now i tried my work in other browser. the target_blank is working in IE browser only in chrome is not working. is that problem in google chrome or to my codes?

Comment: @DevGe – Look at the headers on the HTTP response that delivers the image. Find out what they say the browser should do. Then you can determine which browser is doing The Wrong Thing.